# Spring boot Application Startup failed: nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load keystore

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to enable https in my rest api requests. I have added keystore file "csrportal.p12" in src/main/resources path of my project. Also, added the server.ssl.key-store=classpath:csrportal.p12 in properties file. Still my application fails to startup beacuse it cannot load key store file.

Any ideas how should I specify path in properties?

I have tried code by using "src/main/resources" path but it works locally and not in deployed version. Application does not find any keystore file although it is in the folder and now I have added

```
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:csrportal.p12 using classpath as well.
```

I have added these in my properties file along with other required properties:

```
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
# The path to the keystore containing the certificate
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:csrportal.p12
```

Also I have customized tomcat and accessed keystore file by using code:

```
try {
connector.setAttribute("keystoreFile",
ResourceUtils.getFile(cSRPortalSettings.getServerSslKeyStore()));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot load keystore", 
e);
}
```

I expect that my rest api runs with https://...

but the actual output from logs is:

```
Exception encountered 
during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start 
embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Cannot load keystore",
"Application startup 
failed","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication",
"stack_trace":"org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: 
Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load keystore\n\tat
```

Comment: `ResourceUtils.getFile` requires the resource to be available as a `File` directly on the file system. How are you running your application? If you have packaged it as a jar, `csrportal.p12` will only be available via an `InputStream`. That, I suspect, is why you're getting a `FileNotFoundException`. What happens if you remove your code that's customising the connector? It shouldn't be necessary as Boot will set things up for you based on the properties you've specified.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, if I remove code for customising the connector, I get the following error by sending https request of my api: `Error parsing HTTP request header Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens`

Comment: How are you sending the request? If the client side is using SSL, it must have completed the SSL handshake to get to the point of sending a request. If that's the case, your SSL configuration cannot be at fault. Can you share a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve) of your problem? There are too many unknowns at the moment.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, the client side is okay and it is using SSL. Right now I am not doing configurations on client side. I am only doing SSL configurations on spring boot to make it HTTPS enabled so that my rest api can accept https requests. Also, I can send https requests from postman on my localhost if I set the path to `ResourceUtils.getFile("src/main/resources/csrportal.p12"));` But after deployment, I get file not found exception. Cannot load keystore. So basically the issue is with how to load keystore file. I hope the explanation helps you understand the problem

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, where can I share with you the complete code?